# 3d point cloud registration - parts of textured sphere

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

A spherical object is photographed from 6 different sides (cube faces). Since the radius and camera distance is known, the z coordinate of every pixel in the images can be calculated.

So I have multiple point clouds (nearly half spheres) of the same physical object as `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>`.

I know the rough rotational relationship between the models (90 deg rotations), but to stitch them together to a full sphere correctly I need to know the rigid transform more precisely. How can I achieve this? The shapes have no significance in this case, stitching by color matching would be good. But the [examples in the documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#registration-tutorial) all seem to only consider shapes, not colors.
The overlap of the partial models is about 40 degrees.

Comment: How much overlap do you have between one cloud and the 4 surrounding it?

Comment: It is about 40 degrees. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: That overlap should be enough to find correspondences. Why do you have each cloud in a different color? Is it a way to label the clouds taken from each camera? Can't you get the real textures directly from your camera?. Texture could be useful for a fine registration. Could you show us a visual example of your initial alignment?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. I do have the actual textures from my camera images, and I want to use them in the matching process, but I do not know how to do this. Again, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: If you want to base your registration in texture you may have a look to [CSHOT](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_s_h_o_t_color_estimation.html). Try to obtain features only in overlapping areas (to save time and avoid outliers), and get a rough transformation using inlier correspondences. A fine refinement could be then performed using ICP.
If you want to share more info about your scenario (captures, point clouds...) perhaps I could help you with some pieces of code.

Comment: By now the problem leading to this question was solved in a completely different way. But thanks again for your support.

Comment: You're welcome. If you share the solution as an answer it may be helpful for future readers, it would be nice if you do it when you have a free spot.

Comment: The used solution has nothing to do with point cloud registration at all, sorry. :D